# Custom (user-friendly) ValidatorError message

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, error-handling, mongoose

I'm really new to mongoose, so I was wondering if there is some way to set `custom error message` instead of default one like `Validator "required" failed for path password`.

I would like to set something like `Password is required.` which is more user-friendly.

I wrote some custom validators and set `type` property with this user-friendly error message, but I'm not sure `type` is right placeholder for error message. also there is no way to set custom message on predefined validators like `min, max, required, enum...`

One solution is to check every time `type` property of error thrown and manually assign error message, but think that's validator's job:

```
save model
    if error
        check error type (eg. "required")
        assign fancy error message (eg. "Password is required.")
```

This obviously isn't ideal solution.

I looked at [express-form](https://github.com/dandean/express-form) and [node-validator](https://github.com/chriso/node-validator) but still want to use mongoose validation feature.

Comment: There's also express-validator which works well.

Answer (score 16):

I generally use a helper function for such things. Just mocked this one up to be a little more general than then ones I use. This guy will take all of the "default" validators (required, min, max, etc.) and make their messages a little prettier (according to the `messages` object below), and extract just the message that you passed in your validator for custom validations.

```
function errorHelper(err, cb) {
    //If it isn't a mongoose-validation error, just throw it.
    if (err.name !== 'ValidationError') return cb(err);
    var messages = {
        'required': "%s is required.",
        'min': "%s below minimum.",
        'max': "%s above maximum.",
        'enum': "%s not an allowed value."
    };

    //A validationerror can contain more than one error.
    var errors = [];

    //Loop over the errors object of the Validation Error
    Object.keys(err.errors).forEach(function (field) {
        var eObj = err.errors[field];

        //If we don't have a message for `type`, just push the error through
        if (!messages.hasOwnProperty(eObj.type)) errors.push(eObj.type);

        //Otherwise, use util.format to format the message, and passing the path
        else errors.push(require('util').format(messages[eObj.type], eObj.path));
    });

    return cb(errors);
}
```

And it can be used like this (express router example):

```
function (req, res, next) {
    //generate `user` here
    user.save(function (err) {
        //If we have an error, call the helper, return, and pass it `next`
        //to pass the "user-friendly" errors to
        if (err) return errorHelper(err, next);
    }
}
```

Before:

```
{ message: 'Validation failed',
  name: 'ValidationError',
  errors: 
   { username: 
      { message: 'Validator "required" failed for path username',
        name: 'ValidatorError',
        path: 'username',
        type: 'required' },
     state: 
      { message: 'Validator "enum" failed for path state',
        name: 'ValidatorError',
        path: 'state',
        type: 'enum' },
     email: 
      { message: 'Validator "custom validator here" failed for path email',
        name: 'ValidatorError',
        path: 'email',
        type: 'custom validator here' },
     age: 
      { message: 'Validator "min" failed for path age',
        name: 'ValidatorError',
        path: 'age',
        type: 'min' } } }
```

After:

```
[ 'username is required.',
  'state not an allowed value.',
  'custom validator here',
  'age below minimum.' ]
```

**Edit**: Snap, just realized this was a CoffeeScript question. Not being a CoffeeScript guy, I wouldn't really want to rewrite this in CS. You could always just require it as a `js` file into your CS?

Comment: Thanks man :). I already forked mongoose project and think solved this. I send [pull request](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/pull/753) to mongoose guys. P.S. This isn't CoffeScript at all... I just wanted to write some pseudo code but moderator added CoffeScript tag :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need get the first error message, see the following example:

```
var firstError = err.errors[Object.keys(err.errors)[0]];
return res.status(500).send(firstError.message);
```

Regards, Nicholls